# Zend Framework AjaxLink Complete Failure

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

Having a strange zend framework issue. Although it's most likely something simple, I've been unable to resolve it so far. I have scraped the bottom of stackOverflow and several other community sites, as well as the zend documentation.

Any ajaxLink that I include in my layout refuses to function. They are classed properly, with hash placeholder in href attribute, but the javascript to activate the link is not being included in the page .

`echo $this->jQuery;` statement in layout is also failing. Might be the cause of ajaxLink failure. I have verified that I am properly adding the jQuery view helper in my bootstrap. Have tried using both `ZendX_JQuery::enableView($view);` and `$view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");` methods.

Thanks in advance

Excerpts from the relevant files follow:

bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initViewHelpers()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();

                $view->doctype('HTML4_STRICT');
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8')
                        ->appendName('description', 'Business Club');
        $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
        $view->headTitle('SOU Business Club');

        $view->setHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/helpers', '');
            ZendX_JQuery::enableView($view);
    }
```

dashboardLayout.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->doctype();?>
<html>
<head>
<?php echo $this->headTitle();?>
<?php echo $this->headMeta();?>
<?php
    echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/dashboardStyle.css');
    echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css');
?>
<?php
    echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/paginator.js');
    echo $this->jQuery();
?>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div id="wrapper">
<div><?php include "dashboardHeader.phtml"; ?></div>
<div id="bar">
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'dashboard', 'action'=>'home'))?>">Dashboard  Home</a>|
<?php
echo $this->ajaxLink('Club Roster | ',
      'user/index',
      array('update' => '#content',
            'method' => 'post'),
      array('format' => 'html')
      );
?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'gdata', 'action'=>'index'))?>">Google Docs</a>|
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'books', 'action'=>'index'))?>">Book Sale Management</a>|
</div>
<div id="content" align="center">
<?php
    echo $this->layout()->content;
?>
</div>
<div id="statusBar">
<?php
    $userData = Zend_Registry::get('userData');
    $name = $userData->name;
    $role = $userData->role;
    $status = 'Logged in as: '.'  Name: '.$name.'  Role: '.$role;

echo $status;
?>
<br />
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'authentication', 'action'=>'logout'))?>">Logout</a>
</div>
<div><?php include "dashboardFooter.phtml"; ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML `<head>` output:

```
<head>
<title>SOU Business Club - Member Dashboard</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
<meta name="description" content="Business Club" >
<link href="/css/dashboardStyle.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="/js/jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="/css/dashboardStyle.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/paginator.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap you need to specify where jQuery is, either on your local machine or a CDN. Locally you use:

```
$view->jQuery()->setLocalPath(PATH);
```

Or you could use a CDN such as Google's: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Comment: That's actually one of the reasons that I find this issue so odd. I've tried setting the local path to my jquery installation. No difference. The default path is to the google CDN, so I've tried that as well. I've even tried explicitly linking the google CDN. It is included when explicitly linked, but zend doesn't generate the js for the ajaxlinks. I could write the js myself, but that would defeat the purpose of using the zend library.

Comment: As soon as I use a jquery helper in a loaded view, the jquery link is echoed in the outputted head. my data grid is loaded. It works. My solution is going to be to create a partial view populated with my ajaxLinks that is loaded into the layout rather than being a part of the layout itself. Is there another way to get around this odd ZF idiosyncrasy?

Comment: Okay, so the partial view helper is not going to work. ZF jQuery helper is only active when it is used directly in the content view apparently. There must be a way around this